# How do I rename an attribute using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml like this:

```
<person name="foo" gender = "male" />
```

I want to transform it to

```
<person id="foo" gender="male" />
```

Is there a way to do that using XSLT?

- I will have a lot of child nodes in person
- I will have more attributes in the person.

Comment: That looks more like renaming an attribute to me, unless there's more to your actual scenario that didn't get into the question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is very simple:  Use the identity transform and create a template that transforms the `name` attribute:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@name">
   <xsl:attribute name="id">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

This will leave everything in the document except for `name` attributes exactly as it is.  If you only want to change the `name` attribute on `person` elements, put a more restrictive XPath in the template's `match` attribute, e.g. `person/@name`.

Comment: Short, clean, simple. Excellent answer.

Answer (score -1):

This should do it, not quite sure of the {name()} but you could replace that with "person"

```
> <xsl:template match="person">
>       <xsl:element name="{name()}">
>         <xsl:attribute name="id">
>           <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
>         </xsl:attribute>
>         <xsl:attribute name="gender">
>           <xsl:value-of select="@gender"/>
>         </xsl:attribute>
>       </xsl:element>
>     </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Do I need to create an attribute for every attribute that I have? Can I just copy all the attributes excluding the id?

Comment: It's crazy to use `xsl:element`, an attribute value template, and the `name()` function to create an element whose name you already know.  Replace `<xsl:element>` with `<person>` and you can also replace the `xsl:attribute` elements with AVTs.  Do all that and the answer still won't be right (the answer to kunjaan's question is "no, unless you do it like this"), but it will be less wrong.

Comment: Just trying to provide a generic solution that would work for any element regardless of name.  If it will only ever be for the <person> element, then of course the simpler hard-coded solution would be better.

Comment: If you want to avoid hardcoding the name, use `<xsl:copy>` instead of `<xsl:element name="{name()}">`. Also, your solution strips away other attributes and any child nodes, while the question asks for these to be preserved.

Comment: @markusk: The question didn't *originally* say that other attributes and child nodes would be present at all. That bit was added some 5 hours after the original question was posted.