# How do you use wsdl2java with an invalid wsdl file?

Tags: cxf, msdn, wsdl2java

I am trying to use MSDN's [MTPS](http://services.msdn.microsoft.com/ContentServices/ContentService.asmx), the API for accessing their MSDN content. If I just hand wsdl2java the url to their wsdl I get an NPE ([CXF-5793](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5793)). Daniel Kulp discovered that it is because they have an attribute called "messsage". There is an extra "s".

Cool.. So I search for [renaming an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679443/how-do-i-rename-an-attribute-using-xslt) using xslt and I come up with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@messsage">
        <xsl:attribute name="message">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It turns out that I can't just point wsdl2java to a local file because the wsdl I'm trying to use has a bunch of <xsd:import> directives. So I made scripts to download those files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>XSD Imports for Wget to Fetch</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div>This file is generated so that wget -i can download xsdimport'ed files.</div>
                <xsl:for-each select="//xs:import">
                    <a>
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@schemaLocation" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@schemaLocation" />
                    </a>
                    <br />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```
#!/bin/sh
wget -xNS http://services.msdn.microsoft.com/ContentServices/ContentService.asmx\?wsdl
xsltproc -o services.msdn.microsoft.com/ContentServices/fixedwsdl.xml messsage.xsl services.msdn.microsoft.com/ContentServices/ContentService.asmx\?wsdl
xsltproc -o wget.html wget.xsl services.msdn.microsoft.com/ContentServices/ContentService.asmx\?wsdl
wget -xNSF -i wget.html -B http://services.msdn.microsoft.com/ContentServices/ContentService.asmx\?wsdl 

for filename in services.msdn.microsoft.com/ContentServices/schemas/*.xsd; do
    xsltproc -o "$filename.html" wget.xsl $filename
    wget -xNSF -i "$filename.html" -B http://services.msdn.microsoft.com/ContentServices/schemas/
done

for filename in services.msdn.microsoft.com/ContentServices/schemas/*.xsd; do
    xsltproc -o "$filename.html" wget.xsl $filename
    wget -xNSF -i "$filename.html" -B http://services.msdn.microsoft.com/ContentServices/schemas/
done
```

It doesn't work though. I guess it misses some of them and wsdl2java seems to want to find those scripts in the current working directory anyway. I don't know.

My question is, is there a way to get wsdl2java to apply a xml transformation to the wsdl file before using it? If not, should I continue down this road of using wget and stuff to download the files the wsdl depends on? I'm probably going to look into "flattening" the wsdl file next, but some people have said that <xsd:import>s can't be flattened like <xsd:include>s can. I feel like it is very unlikely that Microsoft can be convinced to fix the wsdl on their end. It appears that it has been this way for a very long time.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be inclined to continue down the path of getting all the referenced schemas. I've used [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) to do it with other troublesome WSDLs. In the (rather old) version 3.6.1 I'm using, there is a function to "export definition" which should download all referenced schemas. Start by loading the corrected WSDL in SoapUI.

Answer (score 0):

So.. What I did was add this proxy to my maven settings. (I'm using the maven plugin to generate these classes.)

```
<proxies>
    <proxy>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <host>localhost</host>
        <port>8080</port>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
```

Then I ran

```
mitmproxy-2.7 --replace /~s/messsage/message
```

It works now. Talk about a build being platform dependent though heh...

Now to go and learn about how to use Web Services.

Thanks for the suggestion unhillbilly but I didn't know how to download every resource that this depended on.