# How to change all Attributes Names with keep the values in XML in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have this in my xml file

```
<CPU> 
<NEW type="DOS" model="SV112">dos-8875</NEW> 
<NEW type="DIN" model="SV544">din-9984</NEW> 
<NEW type="FTP" model="SV774">ftp-9952</NEW> 
<NEW type="DOS" model="SV112">dos-8854</NEW> 
</CPU>
```

and I want to make it like this

```
<CPU> 
<NEW name="DOS" model-no="SV112">dos-8875</NEW> 
<NEW name="DIN" model-no="SV544">din-9984</NEW> 
<NEW name="FTP" model-no="SV774">ftp-9952</NEW> 
<NEW name="DOS" model-no="SV112">dos-8854</NEW> 
</CPU>
```

Here is what I have done so far,  but unfortunately this just changes the first attribute:

```
string path = @"d:\test.xml";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
var element = doc.Root.Element("NEW");
var list = element.Attributes().ToList();
var oldAttr = list.Where(p => p.Name == "type").SingleOrDefault();
if (oldAttr != null)
{
    XAttribute newAttr = new XAttribute("name", oldAttr.Value);
    list.Add(newAttr);
    list.Remove(oldAttr);
    element.ReplaceAttributes(list);
}
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

I want to change all attributes names with keeping its value,  How can this be done with `XDocument`?

Pseudo code:

```
element[0].attribute[0].name = "type";
element[1].attribute[0].name = "type";
element[2].attribute[1].name = "model-no";
```

Comment: I am guessing you need to deserialize this. Take a look at this article describing how to control names etc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The link that you sent for value , but I want for attributes name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't quite do what your pseudo code suggests, as `XAttribute.Name` is not mutable (As an aside, `XElement.Name` is mutable so you can easily change *element* names).

The only option you have is what you're already doing - remove the existing attribute and add another with the same name.  If you want to keep these in the same order per your 'output' XML, then you'll need to replace all the attributes with a new set.

```
foreach (var element in doc.Descendants("NEW"))
{
    element.ReplaceAttributes(
        element.Attributes().Select(MapAttribute));
}
```

Where `MapAttribute` is something like this:

```
private static XAttribute MapAttribute(XAttribute attribute)
{
    switch (attribute.Name.LocalName)
    {
        case "type":
            return new XAttribute("name", attribute.Value);
        case "model":
            return new XAttribute("model-no", attribute.Value);
        default:
            return attribute;
    }
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M5LiwJ) for a working demo.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean this:

```
foreach (var element in xml.Root.Elements()) //or use xml.Descendants("NEW")
{
    var att = element.Attributes().SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name == "model");
    element.SetAttributeValue(XName.Get("model-no"), att?.Value ?? "");
    att.Remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            foreach (XElement descendant in doc.Descendants())
            {
                for (int i = descendant.Attributes().Count() - 1; i > 0; i--)
                {
                    XAttribute attr = descendant.Attributes().Skip(i).FirstOrDefault();
                    switch (attr.Name.LocalName)
                    {
                        case "type":
                            descendant.Add(new XAttribute("name", attr.Value));
                            attr.Remove();
                            break;

                        case "model":
                            descendant.Add(new XAttribute("model-no", attr.Value));
                            attr.Remove();
                            break;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best tool for jobs like is XSLT. You can see how this is done in XSLT [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679443/how-do-i-rename-an-attribute-using-xslt). In your case this would look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@type">
   <xsl:attribute name="name">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@model">
   <xsl:attribute name="model-no">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Check [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693213.aspx) on how to apply XSLT in C#/.NET.

What you need is an `XslCompiledTransform` that will do the transformation:

```
string transformation = "...your XSLT...";

XDocument destinationDoc = new XDocument();
XmlWriter destinationWriter = destinationDoc.CreateWriter()
using (destinationWriter) {  
    XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
    XmlReader transformationReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(transformation));
    using (transformationReader) {
        xslt.Load(transformationReader);  
    }
    XmlReader docReader = doc.CreateReader();
    using (docReader) {
        xslt.Transform(docReader, destinationWriter);
    }
}
```

XSLT is specifically designed for XML transformations like yours and gives you maximum flexibility.

What I generally do is to add an XSLT file to the project, create an assembly resource file and link the XSLT.